# smartgwt TabSet - how to use it for full screen (or percentage)

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Given the code below, how is it possible to use a percentage to get width and hight 
(when I do tabs.setWidth("80%") - it doesn't work).

any idea?

```
    final TabSet tabs = new TabSet(); 
    tabs.setWidth("80%"); //this doesn't work I use tabs.setHeight(600);
    tabs.setHeight(600);
```

Comment: where are you putting the TabSet?, is it a child of a Widget or is it in the RootPanel? according to the documentation "if this is a child of some other canvas, percentages will be based on the inner size of the parentElement's viewport".

Answer (score 0):

Add your TabSet to a Layoutmanager and do the sizing there (do not use size on the TabSet directly):

```
    final TabSet tabs = new TabSet(); 
    //TODO create some tabs
    VLayout vLayout = new VLayout();  
    vLayout.addMember(tabs);
    vLayout.setWidth("100%");
    vLayout.setHeight("100%");
```

See examples how to use VLayout in the smartgwt [showcase - layout](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_layout) . There are also other Layoutmanagers HLayout, VStack, HStack,...